# initializer_list gcc 4.8.1 ubuntu 13.10 qt4

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

I'm developing a software that uses initializer_list. That software compiles fine under all major OS's and different compilers. My own dev machine is a ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3. To use initilizer_lists I have to use std=c++0x.

Now I'm trying to compile it on another machine and get the error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:36:0,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:55,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:50,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:45,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qapplication.h:45,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication:1,
             from /home/chris/scripts/bin/braingl/src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I clearly set that ( -std=c++11 ) in my CMake files CXX_FLAGS but it still fails with the same error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `-std=c++11`?

Comment: you need add -std=c++11

Comment: Yes thought that was clear in the OP, I edited it for clarification. The question basically is, why does it not work even though I set the flag it asks for.

Comment: Well, you had only mentioned `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: You need to show us the actual compiler commandline that produces the error.